# Using Dynamic string output inside Block

Tags: dynamic, output-formatting, scoping, output

Inside a [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), I have (among other things) a string output that is updated during an internal for loop in the following (schematic) way:

```
dynamicTest[] := 
Block[{dynamicstr, i},
 Print["current value: ", Dynamic[dynamicstr]];
  For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
     dynamicstr = ToString[i]; Pause[1];
  ];
 dynamicstr = "Done";
];
```

This function is now called multiple times in another place which results in the following
behavior that I cannot explain:
When I call the Block the second time, the output cell from the first call is also updated again, i.e. both outputs start running from 1 to 10 instead of the first staying at the final value 'Done'
while the second runs from 1 to 10.

I realized that this does not happen when I use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) instead, but I do not understand exactly
why. I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me or point out where it says why that is the case (in case I have missed something in the documentation).

Also, is it possible to use a Block and still reach the desired behavior?

Comment: Module does assigns new names for the local variable. Instead Block only clears the content of the local variables and restores it at the end. However, it uses the same variables.

Comment: I can highly recommend reading [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html)

Answer (score 1):

#### Intro

I'll try to give some quick principals to guide one's thinking about scoping and `Dynamic[]`. `Dynamic[]` is complicated, and this answer will not explain everything.  The Quiz at the end probably reveals this.  Perhaps the OP doesn't even need `Dynamic[]`, as has been suggested.  Perhaps one's actual use-case does need `Dynamic[]`.  In any case, here is the basic beginning advice:  The variables inside `Dynamic[]` should be global ***on purpose*** or inside a `DynamicModule[]` containing the `Dynamic[]`.  For instance, I use `Dynamic[]` *on purpose* to monitor the progress of global variables in a time-consuming computation.

#### Some principals of scoping

`Dynamic[code]` lives "forever," until the output is deleted from the notebook. It outlives kernel sessions. It outlives front end sessions. It is reevaluated when notebooks are reopened. If it is to work "forever," then the dependencies of `code` have to live "forever." `DynamicModule[]` is typically the way one makes this happen (see further down).

`Block[{vars}, code]` hijacks the global variables in `vars`, saves their values, clears (and optionally initializes) them for the execution of `code`. This lasts until `Block[]` has finished evaluating.  Any changes to the values of `vars` happen to the global variables. (This is useful for temporarily resetting system parameters like `$RecursionLimit` or `$MinPrecision` etc.)  Any external `Dynamic[]` that depends on `vars` will be updated with the new values. When `Block[]` is finished and the old values are restored, `Dynamic[]` will again reevaluate its code.

`Module[{vars}, code]` creates unique *global* symbols based on the symbol names of `vars`.  They have the attribute `Temporary`, which means that if the symbols do not leak out of the module, they will be removed after `Module[]` is done.  `Module[]` variables could leak out like this: `Module[{x = 1}, Dynamic[x]]`.  When the kernel session is over, the module variable `x` will be removed. and `Dynamic[x]` will display the unique symbol name for `x` that the `Module[]` created.  The name will vary by session; see [`$ModuleNumber`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ModuleNumber.html).  `Module[]` is somewhat similar to `Block[]`, but its creating new symbols for the `vars` is important.  It explains why the OP sees different behavior for `Module[]`.  It means that every call to `Module[]` creates a new and distinct symbol for `x`; whereas `Block[]` reuses the same global `x` each time, and other any other process may use the same `x`, too.

`DynamicModule[{vars}, code]` lives "forever," until the output is deleted from the notebook.  It stores values for `vars` from session to session (as text in the notebook).  The values will be in the notebook for `Dynamic[]` to use when the notebook is reopened (provided it is inside a `DynamicModule[]` and displayed in the output cell).  These variables are "localized" each time the dynamic output is instantiated.  Instantiation includes when you copy a `DynamicModule[]` output and paste in a notebook (same or different one, it does not matter).  The `vars` are localized in a similar way to `Module[]`: Unique symbols names are created for each instance.  They are recreated, possibly with different names, when the notebook is reopened.  The new names are substituted for the `vars` in the instantiation process.

[*Re "global": Arguably every symbol in Mathematica is global. There is the `` "Global`" `` context, which is for the user-global symbols.  But all symbols are accessible, and they are writable if not `Protected` or `Locked`.  By "global" above, I mean principally the symbols in the `` "Global`" `` and `` "System`" `` contexts.]

#### `Block[{x = 1}, code]`

`Block[{x = 1}, code]` expresses an intention of temporarily resetting the global value of `x` while `code` is executing. The temporary aspect suggests that `Block[{x = 1}, Dynamic[x]]` is a mistake, as it expresses simultaneously that `x` should temporarily be changed as well as permanently be part of the evaluation notebook. One might imagine reasons for doing this on purpose, and therefore, it is not treated as an error.  *Mathematica* will run the code.  You just get red highlighting, which you could change in Preferences, if it annoys you.

#### Output from `DynamicModule[{x = 1}, code]`

```
DynamicModule[{x = 1},
 Print@x;
 Print@Dynamic@x;
 Dynamic@x]
```

> ```
> (*  1  *) 
>
> (*  x$20686492  $*)
>
> (*  1  *)
> ```

The `Print[e]` cells contain their output ***outside*** any `DynamicModule[]`.  In the first output line, the value of `x` is printed.  In the second, because `Dynamic[]` holds `x`, we get a module variable with a module number tacked on (invisibly wrapped in `Dynamic[]`.  The third output is a `DynamicModule[]`:

```
% // InputForm

(*  DynamicModule[{x = 1}, Dynamic[x], DynamicModuleValues :> {}]  *)
```

Note that it is note the same module. The body `code`, a `CompoundExpression[]`, has been evaluated in a module setting, and what we get is the `DynamicModule[]` wrapped around the value of the body.

#### Quiz

What variable does the `Slider[]` control?:

A.

```
 DynamicModule[{x = 1},
  Print@x;
  Print@Dynamic@x;
  Print@Slider@Dynamic@x;
  {Dynamic@x, Dynamic@Hold@x}]
```

B.

```
 DynamicModule[{x = 1},
  Print@x;
  Print@Dynamic@x;
  {Dynamic@x, Dynamic@Hold@x, Slider[Dynamic@x]}]
```

Bonus: Why is the `x` different in `Print@Dynamic@x` and `Dynamic@Hold@x`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't require the use of Dynamic. In fact, you may have noticed that dynamicstr is highlighted in red inside Dynamic[dynamicstr] because it's not quite correct to use Block or Module with Dynamic; DynamicModule is recommended instead.

If I remove the Dynamic from your code and add some extra Print statements, I get the following:

```
dynamicTest[] := 
Block[{dynamicstr, i},
 Print["current value: ", dynamicstr];
  For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
     dynamicstr = ToString[i];Print[dynamicstr];
  ];
 dynamicstr = "Done";Print[dynamicstr];
];


dynamicTest[]
```

current value: dynamicstr

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Done

(I also removed the Pause.)

Running it a second time:

```
dynamicTest[]

current value: dynamicstr

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Done
```

Using Module instead of Block makes no difference.

```
dynamicTest2[] := 
Module[{dynamicstr, i},
 Print["current value: ", dynamicstr];
  For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
     dynamicstr = ToString[i];Print[dynamicstr];
  ];
 dynamicstr = "Done";Print[dynamicstr];
];


dynamicTest2[]

current value: dynamicstr$29032

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Done

dynamicTest2[]

current value: dynamicstr$29035

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Done
```

To get the behavior you want, you'll need to move your variable outside of any scoping construct and make it global. Scoping constructs localize their variables lexically or dynamically, to prevent retaining values set by code inside across calls.

```
dynamicstr;
dynamicTest3[] := 
Block[{i},
 Print["current value: ", dynamicstr];
  For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
     dynamicstr = ToString[i];Print[dynamicstr];
  ];
 dynamicstr = "Done";Print[dynamicstr];
];


dynamicTest3[]

current value: dynamicstr

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Done

dynamicTest3[]

current value: Done

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Done
```

Notice that for the second run, the variable is still set to "Done" from the first pass.